# Same SSIS package parallely executing with different parameters through batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I have a SSIS package with a Data Flow Task containing an OLEDB source and OLEDB Destination. Again I have a Batch file(.bat file) to execute the SSIS package, using dtexec command. In the batch file I am setting the ConnectionString property of the oledb destination's connection manager. 
I need the SSIS package to get executed parallely with different values for the Destination ConnectionString since I have to populate multiple Destination tables simulatneously.

How can I change the batch file commands so that I can execute the same SSIS package parallely at the same time, setting different values for the Destination connection Manager's Connection string

Comment: Which version of SSIS are you running? I ask because SSIS 2012 offers new and different solutions for this scenario.

Comment: I am using SSIS version 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dbenham is correct. Use the Start command in your batch file (using your example):

start "Instance 1" dtexec /FILE "C:\Users\Desktop\SSIS\PKG.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT " 2 " /SET "\Package.Connections[Destination].Properties[ConnectionString]";\""Data Source=datasrc1;Initial Catalog=db1;User ID=usrid;Password =pswd;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"\"

start "Instance 2" dtexec /FILE "C:\Users\Desktop\SSIS\PKG.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT " 2 " /SET "\Package.Connections[Destination].Properties[ConnectionString]";\""Data Source=datasrc2;Initial Catalog=dbn2;User ID=usrid;Password =pswd;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"\"

These will execute in parallel with different Destination ConnectionString values.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the START command To run console applications in parallel. Don't forget to add a title as the first parameter. You can use empty quotes as the first parameter for an empty title.

```
start "" yourProgram.exe parameter1 parameter2 ...
```

Each command you start will run in its own console window. Type `start /?` or `help start` from a command prompt to get more information.

Comment: The code in my batch file is                                        dtexec /FILE "C:\Users\Desktop\SSIS\PKG.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT " 2 " /SET "\Package.Connections[Destination].Properties[ConnectionString]";\""Data Source=datasrc1;Initial Catalog=db1;User ID=usrid;Password =pswd;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"\" . I need to execute the ssis package PKG.dtsx simultaneously twice with another value for destination connection string.ie. \""Data Source=datasrc2;Initial Catalog=dbn2;User ID=usrid;Password =pswd;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;"\". How can I modify my batch file to accomplish this?